# Create after plugin for Magento\Framework\DataObject.php getData function

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am trying to create after plugin for Magento\Framework\DataObject.php getData function but it seems not working also not getting sku value in it.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **di.xml** file in **Vendor/Module/etc** directory to configure the plugin and add the below code.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Framework\DataObject">
    <plugin name="custom_dataobject_plugin" type="MageINIC\BundleSelectionImage\Plugin\DataObjectPlugin"
            sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
     </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create a **DataObjectPlugin.php** file in **Vendor/Module/Plugin** directory and add the below code.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

   class DataObjectPlugin
   {
      public function afterGetData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $subject, $result)
      {
        // Perform your custom logic here

        return $result;
      }
   }
   ```
3. Run the below commands and check.
   **php bin/magento s:d:c**

I am trying to create after plugin for
Magento\Framework\DataObject.php getData function in my local setup
it working properly.

Please let me know still if you get issue.

Comment: Plugin i have created successfully but not getting sku value in plugin only sku key is coming.

Comment: please share you code here

Comment: namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class DataObjectPlugin
{
   public function afterGetData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $subject, $result)
   {
     print_r($result['sku']);die;

     return $result;
   }
}

Comment: Need to get sku value here

Comment: please try this 
if (isset($result['sku'])) {
            $sku = $result['sku'];
            print_r($sku);exit;

        }